# C++ template class overload [] operator

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, operator-overloading

I would like to overload the [] operator for a template class in respect with the template parameters. Like so:

```
template<
    typename T,
    template<typename> class Property, 
    template<typename> class Key1, 
    template<typename> class Key2>
class a_map 
{
public:
    const Property<T>& operator[](const Key1<T>& k) const
    { return _values[k.index()]; }
    const Property<T>& operator[](const Key2<T>& k) const
    { return _values[k.index()]; }
protected:
    std::vector<Property<T> > _values;
};
```

I would use this class like so:

```
int main()
{
    a_map<float, prop, key_a, key_b> pm;
}
```

Basically I want to be able to access the elements inside the `_values` vector without having to worry to much about the `Key` types. All that matters is that they have an `index()` member.

However I get the following error

> error C2535: 'const Property &a_map::operator
>   [](const Key1 &) const' : member function already defined or
>   declared

even though `key_a` and `key_b` are two totaly different <strike>types</strike> class templates.

Am I missing something? Is the compiler afraid that in certain situation `Key1<T>` and `Key2<T>` might actually be the same type?

**Edit**
These are the class templates used in `main`

```
template<typename T>
struct prop 
{
    T weight;
    T height;
};


template<typename T>
class key_a
{
public:
    int index() { return _i; }
private:
    int _i;
};

template<typename T>
class key_b
{
public:
    int index() { return 3; } // Always return 3
```

**Edit**
I'm using MVC++ 2008 compiler.

Comment: Are you 100% confident that `Key1` and `Key2` are different templates? Try `std::vector` and `std::list` as a test, or something like that.

Comment: `key_a` and `key_b` - types? According to your declaration `key_a` and `key_b` must be class *templates*, not types. You declared your 2nd, 3rd and 4th template parameters as *template-template* parameters. So, you have to specify *templates* as arguments. If `key_a` and `key_b` are simply *types*, your code should not even compile. Provide a specific example of what is `key_a` and `key_b` in your test that gives you that error.

Comment: Is this a compiler error or a linker error?

Comment: @AndreyT my bad. key_a and key_b are indeed class templates. I've made the corrections.

Comment: @Code-Guru I believe it's a compiler error.

Comment: If you are using a command-line compiler, will you give the full command you are using to compile as well as the lines of output up to the error message you gave in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Since both of your operator[] are the same except for the argument type, why not template them?

```
    template <typename TT>
    const Property<T>& operator[](const TT& k) const
    {
        return _values[k.index()];
    }
```

Comment: because I would like a better control over key types. I want the compiler to not allow certain types of keys. (Only Key1 and Key2 are allowed)

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: I'd rather lean towards "no excuse for complicating it over 2 lines", but each to their own...

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your `index()` functions as `const` because inside the `a_map` template you are invoking them through `const` objects

```
template<typename T> class key_a {
public:
    int index() const // <- `const` is necessary
      { return _i; }
private:
    int _i;
};

template<typename T> class key_b {
public:
    int index() const // <- `const` is necessary
      { return 3; } 
};
```

But otherwise, everything compiles and work fine for me.

---

Tried it in VS2010 compiler and get the same error as yours. This is obviously a compiler bug in MSVC++ compilers. Handling of template-template arguments is implemented incorrectly.

To work around the problem I was able to use this technique

```
template<
    typename T,
    template<typename> class Property, 
    template<typename> class Key1, 
    template<typename> class Key2>
class a_map 
{
public:
    const Property<T>& operator[](const typename Key1<T>::self& k) const
    { return _values[k.index()]; }
    const Property<T>& operator[](const typename Key2<T>::self& k) const
    { return _values[k.index()]; }
protected:
    std::vector<Property<T> > _values;
};
```

and define the key templates as

```
template<typename T> class key_a {
public:
    typedef key_a self;
    int index() const { return _i; }
private:
    int _i;
};

template<typename T> class key_b {
public:
    typedef key_b self;
    int index() const { return 3; } 
};
```

This is inelegant, but it makes it work correctly with MSVC++ compilers.

Answer (score 0):

Compiles fine like this... note how Prop/K1/K2 should be defined.

```
#include <vector>

template<
    typename T,
    template<typename> class Property, 
    template<typename> class Key1, 
    template<typename> class Key2>
class a_map 
{
public:
    const Property<T>& operator[](const Key1<T>& k) const
    { return _values[k.index()]; }
    const Property<T>& operator[](const Key2<T>& k) const
    { return _values[k.index()]; }
protected:
    std::vector<Property<T> > _values;
};

template <typename T> struct K1 { int index() const { return 0; } };
template <typename T> struct K2 { int index() const { return 0; } };
template <typename T> struct Prop { };

int main()
{
    a_map<float, Prop, K1, K2> m;
}
```

Comment: Remember that the compiler doesn't even look at template functions that are not used. Your main function does not use `operator[]` so those two routines are not checked. Add this `K1<int> k1; m[k1];` and you will get `error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘m[k1]`

Comment: @Adam: Of course, there's no match: in Tony's example the `a_map` is instantiated with `T = float`. Why are you trying to use `K1<int>`?

Comment: @Tony Delroy I've tried your exact code and I still get the error in my comiler MVSC 2008

Comment: @Adam: the compiler does look at functions that aren't used - though not as thoroughly - that's why you need to use `typename` sometimes so they can pass checking while the template parameters aren't known....  I was confident enough that the error was in this phase I didn't feel the need to use them ;-).

Comment: @Iam: ouch - using GNU here on Linux - you might want to try http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/ - if it works there, then it's probably your compiler....